# Runtime error for reversing bytes in Solidity!

Tags: solidity, error, bug

I decided to use the below code to reverse bytes32 values in Solidity:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Reverse{

    function reverse(bytes32 pad) pure public returns(bytes memory){
        bytes memory reversePad;
        for(uint i=32;i>0;i--){
            reversePad[32-i]=pad[i];
        }
    }
}
```

But after deployment, Whenever I try to run `reverse()` this error occurs:

```
data: {
    '0x708f5fe50e73a6fbd6404fd0f7dbae50c9617fe151f7d53843331b86dd117f8b': {
      error: 'revert',
      program_counter: 133,
      return: '0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000032'
    },
    stack: 'RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n' +
      '    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults ...
```

I don't know what it is and how I should eliminate it!

Comment: what do you mean by reverse bytes32 btw ? do you want to reverse the bits at each position ? also why the returned type is bytes not bytes32 again ?

Comment: @SujithSomraaj I mean, For example, if my `bytes32 pad` is `0x123...def` I sort the bytes to `0xfed...321`. I don't want reverse bits at each position I want to reverse bytes at each position. Returned type is `bytes` because I can't modify a `bytes32` element in `reverse()` as I did it by `bytes` in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function reverse(bytes32 pad) pure public returns(bytes memory){
    string memory temp = new string(pad.length);
    bytes memory reversed = bytes(temp);

    for(uint256 i=0; i<pad.length; i++) {
        reversed[pad.length - 1 - i] = pad[i];
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

This should help you reverse the bytes32 in-terms of bytes